# Que abordagem deve ser utilizada em controllers do tipo resource para listar e buscar itens?

Tags: laravel

Criei o controller **ArtigoController** do tipo *resource*, logo tenho os [verbos e rotas padrões](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers). Utilizo o método **index** do meu controller para listar todos os artigos (paginados):

```
$artigos = Artigo::orderBy('edicao', 'desc')->paginate(25);
return view('painel.artigos.listar', compact('artigos'));
```

A questão é que na minha view **listar.blade.php**, além de listar tudo, também tenho um input de busca, que em teoria faz a busca e popula essa mesma view, pelo que sei o método **index** do resource não aceita parâmetros de entrada, neste caso o melhor é no caso da busca chamar outro controller e este apontar de volta para a view?

Estou utilizando Laravel 5.6

Answer (score 1):

Uma abordagem que pode ser utilizada é aceitar *query strings* para filtrar no `index`.

```
public function index(Request $request) 
{
    $query = $request->query('campo1', 'campo2');
    // Ou todos os campos.. é interessante uma validação aqui
    $query = $request->query();

    $artigos = Artigo::where($query)->orderBy('edicao', 'desc')->paginate(25);

    return view('painel.artigos.listar', compact('artigos'));
}
```

Sua *url* pode ser algo parecido com isso:

`/artigos?campo1=123&campo2=234`

Comment: Mas neste caso como estamos falando de resource, se eu passar algum parâmetro não estaria caindo em outro método como show?

Comment: Não pois ele so vai para outro resource se você usar seguimento de url tipo /artigo/campo

Comment: Nesse caso não é um parâmetro na url, é simplesmente um argumento extra para o método. Repare que é usado um `?` para enviar os campos.